# How to extract content from mysql file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

My old wordpress site has been damaged, i have the mysql database file `.sql` and want to extract the content from this file. can anyone help me please?

Comment: export it to cvs file and then import to the newly created one. That simple!

Comment: @Grasper some of the data has been damaged? any way to make it restore it  correctly

Comment: if you don't have a back-up there is nothing that can help.